# patch value with condition and null object

Tags: angular, typescript

I have this model `FOTreesDetailsModel` 
in first condition - I need to fill `treeInfoModel`
but also in null values. How should I do it?

```
export interface FOTreesDetailsModel {
  selectedType: number;
  foExempSurveyRequestModel?: FOExempSurveyRequestModel | {};
  treeInfoModel?: FOTreeInfoModel | {};
}
```

I am getting error of

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of null
```

when Im doing it in the regular way

```
   const users = value.treeInfoModel;
        const users2 = this.fg.get('treeInfoModel');
        users2.patchValue(users);
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do. Could you rephrase your question and provide more code?

Comment: Make sure to provide sufficient context when asking question. When error happens in your custom function, provide the code of your custom function. No one knows what is `value`, what is `fg`, what is `patchValue`.